# How can I get the full return value from an Address Method?

Tags: excel, vba, string, string-length

I have a column of data in an Excel sheet which has empty cells distributed in it.  I have a matching column of date/time information which does not have empty cells in it. I need to delete from the date/time column those elements which match with the empty cells in the data column.
e.g. I need to delete the Time elements for 5 and 9.

```
Time Data
   1    1
   2    2
   3    3
   4    4
   5
   6    5
   7    6
   8    7
   9
  10    8   
  11    9
  12   10
```

Using VBA I have generated a list of the blank cells in the Data column with this code:

```
deleteCells = sht.Columns(n).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Address _
    RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False
```

and then I delete the accompanying elements of the time column with the following code.

```
destSht.Range(deleteCells).Offset(0, n - 1).Clear
destSht.Columns(2*n-1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Copy _
    Destination:=destSht.Columns(tempcol)
destSht.Columns(tempcol).Copy Destination:=destSht.Columns(2*n-1)`
```

(The Offset means delete one column to the left of the reference given, the following two lines then copy the data to a temporary location and in the process close up the gaps created in the column, then copy it back again.)

But, the returned string for `deleteCells` is truncated at 256 characters (Len(deleteCells) => 256).  This doesn't cover all the cell references I need to delete.

How can I get the Address to return a longer string? If this won't return more than 256 characters, how can I get the full list of cells I need to eliminate from my Time column in order to have a contiguous Data column?

Comment: Why use the address at all? You already have a Range object, so just loop through its Areas collection and delete the offset range for each area.

Comment: @Rory - That's a good hint. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

@Rory is suggesting you do something like this...
Change the column letter offset value as needed. Note: If you use a negative number that would offset past Col A, you will get an error.

```
For Each cell In Range("B2:B" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)
    If cell = "" Then
        cell.Offset(, -1).Clear
    End If
Next cell
```

Comment: So with the hint from @rory I got the following code:
    Set rngDeleteCells = sht.Clumns(n).SpecialCells(xlTypeBlanks)
    For Each delRange in rngDeleteCells.Areas
        destSht.Range(delRange.Offset(0,n-1).Address).Clear
    Nest delRange

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the `AutoFilter` and the `SpecialCells` method:

You may have to change the worksheet and cell references in the code depending on where your table is located:

```
Option Explicit
Sub delRowsWithBlanks()
    Dim R As Range, WS As Worksheet
    Dim rArea As Range, lrowCount As Long

Set WS = Worksheets("sheet3")
With WS
    Set R = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Resize(columnsize:=2)
End With

R.AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:="="
lrowCount = 0
    For Each rArea In R.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas
        lrowCount = lrowCount + rArea.Rows.Count
    Next rArea

If lrowCount > 1 Then 'assumes header row
    R.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
End If

R.AutoFilter

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting an "Answer" to get the formatting correct and to post up my final solution:

```
rngDeleteCells = sht.Columns(n).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
For Each delRange In rngDeleteCells.Areas
    destSht.Range(delRange.Offset(0, n - 1).Address).Clear
Next delRange
```

I have to use the `.Address` for each `delRange` so I can then offset to a different column in a different sheet for the deletion.

Thanks to @rory and @GMalc for their help.